# Can a third party dll be made to use log4Net 1.2.11, not 1.2.10

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

Currently, I have code that:
1) uses log4Net 1.2.10
2) uses a third party dll to gain access to it's associated third party software api, this dll also uses log4Net 1.2.10

My code must maintain access to this third party api, and there is no other available way to gain the access other than using the dll.  As mentioned above, that dll is compiled against log4Net 1.2.10.

I would like to upgrade all of my system to use log4Net 1.2.11, however doing this causes the third party dll to error out any time I call it as it cannot find log4Net 1.2.10.

Is there a way to have my software compiled with log4Net 1.2.11 where my software is only shipped with log4Net 1.2.11, yet make the third party dll think that it is really log4Net 1.2.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have problems, the log4net team changed their strong name signing key between 10 and 11, see this for an explanation:

http://haacked.com/archive/2012/02/16/changing-a-strong-name-is-a-major-breaking-change.aspx

Basically, you cannot redirect to assemblies with a different signing key.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes.. Look at the assembly binding redirect tag in web/app.config.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: But the downside is that the library assembly must be registered to Global Assembly Cache (GAC).